# Variables Not Set Intermittently

Tags: swift

The app I'm working walks the user through an interview and spits out a PDF with product recommendations based on their answers. I'm currently having a problem with some phones not setting the variables properly at unpredictable times.

The data is stored in a class instance named "newTracker", and (for the scope of this question) the answers are stored as bool. The example code is from a screen with only a single question, a UISwitch, and a "Next" button.

```
class viewWireVolume: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var outWireVolume: UISwitch!

    // MARK: Init

    func UIInit(_ animated: Bool) {

        outWireVolume.setOn(newTracker.customerMoreThanOneWire, animated: animated)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIInit(false)

    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func actionWireVolume(_ sender: Any) { newTracker.customerMoreThanOneWire = outWireVolume.isOn }

    // MARK: Interface

}
```

Most of the time this code works fine, but once in a while, it won't save the variable newTracker.customerMoreThanOneWire. When it happens, it happens all over the app, and the code is structured the same. I had a problem in the past where it *was* saving the variable properly, just not setting the initial switch state properly, but in this instance, it's not saving things at all.

Would it help if the variables were set on Value Change instead of Touch Up Inside? I'm perplexed as to why this only happens at random.
I have had one of the phones in my hands when this went down, and there were no other apps running in the background, the OS was updated, and there didn't seem to be any shenanigans like jailbreaking or anything else happening.

I have not been able to replicate this with an emulator or a phone hooked into my development machine.

Any insights?

EDIT: Here is the answer tracker code.

```
class AnswerTracker: NSObject {

// MARK: Variables

/// Name of the business as type: String
var businessName = ""

// Customer Entity Type
var entityType: Int = 0                                     // 0 = None Selected, 1 - 7 = Corp, LLC, Part, LP, SP, NP, Muni

// How will customers pay?
var customerPayCredit: Bool = false
var customerPayChecks: Bool = false
var customerPayCash: Bool = false
var customerPayDirectDebit: Bool = false

// How will checks be deposited?
var customerDepositChecksOffice: Bool = false
var customerDepositChecksBranch: Bool = false
var customerDepositChecksATM: Bool = false
var customerDepositChecksNight: Bool = false

// How will cash be deposited?
var customerDepositCashBranch: Bool = false
var customerDepositCashATM: Bool = false
var customerDepositCashNight: Bool = false

// How will you pay vendors?
var customerPayVendorsOnline: Bool = false
var customerPayVendorsCheck: Bool = false
var customerPayVendorsCredit: Bool = false
var customerPayVendorsDebit: Bool = false
var customerPayVendorsWire: Bool = false
var customerPayVendorsTransfer: Bool = false

// Do you want to stap unauthed checks?
var customerPreventUnauthedChecks: Bool = false

// How will you do wire transfers?
var customerWireInitiateOnline: Bool = false
var customerWireRequestOnline: Bool = false
var customerWireRequestBranch: Bool = false

// Will you regularly do more than one wire per month?
var customerMoreThanOneWire: Bool = false

// How will you pay your employees?
var customerEmployeePayCheck: Bool = false
var customerEmployeePayDirect: Bool = false
var customerEmployeePayCompany: Bool = false

// How will you manage your accounts?
var customerManageAccountsOnlineSingle: Bool = false
var customerManageAccountsOnlineMultiple: Bool = false
var customerManageAccountsBranch: Bool = false

// How will you get your account statements?
var customerAccountStatementsOnline: Bool = false
var customerAccountStatementsPaper: Bool = false

// What will you do with excess funds?
var customerExcessFundsSweep: Bool = false
var customerExcessFundsSavings: Bool = false
var customerExcessFundsCD: Bool = false
var customerExcessFundsFDIC: Bool = false

// How will you handle overdrafts?
var customerOverdraftsLineOfCredit: Bool = false

// Additional lending?
var customerLoansAndLinesFunding: Bool = false
var customerLoansAndLinesRefi: Bool = false

// Would you like to maintain a $3,500 dailyy balance to earn interest?
var customerReceiveInterest: Bool = false

// Would you like to switch your existing accounts to First Federal automatically?
var customerMoveAccounts: Bool = false

// Create a custom class to track answers as someone moves through the app.

override init() // No initialization needed, just a holder in case it's needed in teh future
{
    super.init()
}


/// This function resets ALL of the data stored in the currently instanced AnswerTracker class.
///
/// - Parameter confirm: You must send with "Yes" or the function will not reset the data.
/// - Returns: Returns Bool: true if successful, and Bool: false on failure.
func resetData(confirm: String) -> Bool {

    if confirm == "Yes" {
        businessName = ""
        entityType = 0
        customerPayCredit = false
        customerPayCredit = false
        customerPayChecks = false
        customerPayCash = false
        customerPayDirectDebit = false
        customerDepositChecksOffice = false
        customerDepositChecksBranch = false
        customerDepositChecksATM = false
        customerDepositChecksNight = false
        customerDepositCashBranch = false
        customerDepositCashATM = false
        customerDepositCashNight = false
        customerPayVendorsOnline = false
        customerPayVendorsCheck = false
        customerPayVendorsCredit = false
        customerPayVendorsDebit = false
        customerPayVendorsWire = false
        customerPayVendorsTransfer = false
        customerPreventUnauthedChecks = false
        customerWireInitiateOnline = false
        customerWireRequestOnline = false
        customerWireRequestBranch = false
        customerMoreThanOneWire = false
        customerEmployeePayCheck = false
        customerEmployeePayDirect = false
        customerEmployeePayCompany = false
        customerManageAccountsOnlineSingle = false
        customerManageAccountsOnlineMultiple = false
        customerManageAccountsBranch = false
        customerAccountStatementsOnline = false
        customerAccountStatementsPaper = false
        customerExcessFundsSweep = false
        customerExcessFundsSavings = false
        customerExcessFundsCD = false
        customerExcessFundsFDIC = false
        customerOverdraftsLineOfCredit = false
        customerLoansAndLinesFunding = false
        customerLoansAndLinesRefi = false
        customerReceiveInterest = false
        customerMoveAccounts = false
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the newTracker class code?

Comment: Let me edit my question to include it.

Comment: Where is the newTracker variable initialized ?  The AnswerTracker class doesn't seem to persist its data anywhere so if your various views are not using the same instance (of newTracker) or if it gets reinitialized somewhere, that could explain why values appear to not be saved.

Comment: It's initialized at beginning of ViewController.swift

let newTracker = AnswerTracker()

Being that it's for a financial institution, it can't save data long-term. So if the app is closed (and closed in the background), the phone is restarted, or resetData() is called, the data is lost forever. That part is according to the wishes of audit/security/etc. It has been good about saving things for that session except on these rare occasions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original question, I pondered: "Would it help if the variables were set on Value Change instead of Touch Up Inside?" That turns out to be the entire solution.

For some reason, hooking those UISwitch actions to TouchUpInside works most of the time. As it runs on progressively older hardware, it seems to up your chance that the action will fire slightly before the switch has finished changing its value, therefore writing the incorrect value to the variable.

I switched everything over to Value Change, and it has been flawless with my beta group ever since.